# Official ELF reference & ignoring DT_RPATH in shared libraries

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, elf

What is the official ELF format reference for Linux?

There is the [ELF 1.2](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf) specification, which is from 1995 and outdated (does not include `DT_RUNPATH` for instance).

But apart from that, it seems there is only a *draft* version [System V Application Binary Interface](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2003-12-17/contents.html) from 2003. I can't seem to find a version that's not a draft.

Then, there is an [Oracle Solaris version](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/glcfv.html#scrolltoc), which seems to be based on that draft.

Notably the 2003 draft and the Solaris version seem to disagree on whether `DT_RPATH` is to be ignored on shared libraries or not; compare the tables [2003 draft](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2003-12-17/ch5.dynamic.html#tag_encodings) and [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-42444.html#chapter6-tbl-52). They should be ignored according to that 2003 draft, they should not be according to Solaris.

On my Ubuntu 16 machine, it seems the runtime linker does *not* ignore `DT_RPATH` on shared libraries, so it looks like it's following the Solaris specs, not the 2003 draft.

What is supposed to be the official ELF specification for Linux?

---

Edit: from LSB 5.0.0:

> LSB-conforming implementations shall support the object file information and system actions that create running programs as specified in the System V ABI and System V ABI Update and as further required by this specification and the relevant architecture specific part of the LSB Core Specification.

I don't see the LSB document mention how to deal with DT_RPATH on shared libraries. Does that mean `ld` is not conforming to LSB as it should ignore RPATH on shared libraries?

Comment: Presumably the one from LSB? https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-AMD64/LSB-Core-AMD64/elf-amd64.html

Comment: Ah yes, https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic.html#AEN1798 is the relevant section. However, it remains unclear whether or not DT_RPATH should be ignored in shared libraries or not.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're only talking of shared libraries. Dunno then. Just checking: you did see the note about it and `DT_RUNPATH` in the System V ABI update, right?